# google page speed up-Optimize css delivery

Tags: css, performance, .htaccess, optimization, render

Hello as you can see i have a big problem with my css. I want to combine my css files into one to optimize css dleivery and speed up my site according to google page speed insights.

I have tried many solutions but nothing happens. I thought it would be easy to combine my css but now i take my wordsback.Can any give me a reliable and easy solution?
I have tried to use combine_css in my htaccess file but nothing happens...
Thanks in advance

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/0_reset_all_css.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/loading.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/anetoi_ads.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/anetoi_fb.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/footer_anetoi.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/header.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/fast_navbar.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/left_navigation_bar.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/right_navigation_bar.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/pagination.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/right_navigation_bar_options.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="anetoi_css/anetoi_css.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: did you install the pagespeed module on your server ? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/using

Comment: How exactly are you combining your CSS?

Comment: with an online tool... i only have one single css file

Answer (score 0):

You can put all CSS here. And save it in one file. (obviously follow the order of CSS)

http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: i tried your suggestion. I created one single css file and all the css is in one single line, but nothing happens google page speed up is the same.

Comment: It is not possible. Please give me your page link.

Comment: Your CSS is pass the Google PageSpeed Insights.

Here is reasult.
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fanetoi.com%2Fanetoi.php&tab=desktop

Comment: No its says Should Fix:

Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
http://anetoi.com/anetoi_css/anetoi_css.min.css

Comment: Is "jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" this CSS is automatically added by jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js ?